# DevOps pipeline on self-hosted MacOS agent fails on NuGet package restore but works on Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, macos-catalina, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I faced a problem with running a DevOps pipeline on self-hosted MacOS (Catalina) build agent and it fails on the step NuGet Package Restore. The same step is successful when run on Azure Pipeline agent.

The error is:

> Unable to locate executable file: 'mono'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.

Comment: Do you have mono installed on your build agent? Is it in the `path` variable for the user account that is running your build agent?

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has [configure the mono in the hosted agent](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md#mono), so you can run the pipeline successfully via hosted agent.
Self-hosted agent need configure it and then you can run the pipeline successfully.

Configure mono

1. [Install mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/mac/) on the local machine which has installed the self-hosted agent
2. After the installation completed successfully, run the [sample](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/) to verify Mono is working correctly.
3. Configure the environment variable of mono on the local machine.